# prevent the behabiour of a link when we click on a span which is inside the link tag javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Hi i am using ng repeat on a div using angualar js.
This div has a link tag inside it which is wrapping the while tags.the a link tag also has a span tag which has a class `btnConatctme` when i click on this span then a bootstarp modal is popping up but when the page is also redirecting to the src in the link tag.i have also tried to use this

```
$('.btnConatctme').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

but still tha page is redirecting 
what i want to do is when we click on the whole a link then the page should redirect to the src which is given in the a link tag.but when we click on `btnConatctme` span then the bootstarp modal should popup and page does not redirect to next page 
here is my full code of the div which is inside ng-repeat

```
<div class="todo-tasklist"  >
   <a href="{{ url('post-shipments/user_view') }}" class="divShipments">
        <div class="todo-tasklist-item todo-tasklist-item-border-green">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <img class="todo-userpic pull-left" src="{{ url('default/img/document.jpg') }}">
              <div class="todo-tasklist-item-title"> shipment Name 
                <span class="pull-right">
                    <span class="todo-tasklist-badge"> 21 DAYS LEFT</span>&nbsp;
                    <span class="todo-tasklist-badge btnConatctme"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Contact me</span>&nbsp;
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

here is the website page link on which i am using it
i am using angular js in it to 
kindly help me on this it will be really appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like below. Hope this will help you.

```
$('body').on('click', '.divShipments', function(e){
     if(e.target.className=='btnConatctme') 
         e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: it is not working page is still redirecting to next page and add alert in the click event then the alert does not even show

Comment: Your elements may be auto generated. See the updated answer. @usama

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.btnConatctme').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Alternative:

```
$('.btnConatctme').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: above both are not working can you please give me an other alternative solution